# Obfuscating resource strings that may give away too much information about programming logic

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, android-resources, android-lvl

I currently use a combination of LVL and Proguard as a first line of defence against piracy.

However, what about the resource strings?  For example, if there is a resource string like "License check failed" then doesn't the pirate simply need to trace that resource id back to where it was used in the code?  In fact, this is also true if the string is something generic like "Please contact dev".

What is the best approach?

Comment: the reference to this string in the code is obfuscated, so it's not even a hook in

Comment: From the string you can get to the obfuscated reference and that gives you (or is?) the resource id, which the pirate could then search on, no?

Comment: But the resource id is in the R.java file, and this being a java file; is obfuscated. (I may be wrong)

Comment: Try too hard and they'll crack it in 1 day instead of 3. ;)

Comment: A key question is, how easy is it to map a resource string like "License check failed" to the corresponding resource id.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you define a resource string, you will probably define or use it in:

- the string resource file *res/values/strings.xml*,
- layout files *res/layout/*.xml*,
- the generated resource file *R.java*,
- your java code *src/**.java*.

After compilation, the resource string, its name, and its integer code end up in:

- the resource file *resources.arsc* (string, name, and code),
- the resource class *R$string.class* (name, code),
- your compiled code ***.class* (inlined code).

ProGuard will remove *R$string.class* entirely, but Android decompilers can reconstruct all information from *resources.arsc*. It still takes a bit of work, but the strings may indeed hint at the purpose of the code (along with certain API calls).

You can improve on this by encrypting/obfuscating the strings in your code and by using reflection to access certain APIs, as suggested in Google's presentation [Evading Pirates and Stopping Vampires](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnSNCXR9fbY&lr=1).

ProGuard's closed-source sibling for Android [DexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard) can encrypt strings for you (along with API calls and entire classes), probably more effectively than you could achieve manually, and without burdening the source code.

(I am the developer of ProGuard and DexGuard)

Comment: Can anyone confirm if the latest version of Lucky Patcher or the modded Google Play Store version from the hacker ChelpuS has defeated DexGuard? If it does, then it's not worth me buying DexGuard to protect my Android apps.

Comment: @ChuongPham Very funny the DexGuard developer didn't answer your question in the comment xD

Answer (score 5):

When i want to conceal important strings in android i put them in a c/c++ library. then i use a JNI call to retrieve them.  In the c library i go even further, i convert the string to hexadecimal and when im retrieve the same string i convert it to integer again from hexadecimal.  When a hacker tries to view the c/c++ library it will be very difficult to find your secret string (especially if there converted to hexadecimal).

here is a nice [article](https://androidsecurity.info/storing-your-secure-information-in-the-ndk/) and how to get started doing that.

Comment: 404 Not Found :)

Comment: Sounds a bit like this library https://github.com/klaxit/HiddenSecrets